# Checking if the element exist without having to add pause

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

I have a function that checks if the element exists it performs a certain action. Currently, my code is working perfectly fine however I do not want to add a pause in my code. If I remove the pause my test skips the `consumerApp.$(HomeScreen.closeButton).click();`

```
logout () {
        driver.pause(2000)
        if (consumerApp.$(HomeScreen.closeButton).isDisplayed()) {
            consumerApp.$(HomeScreen.closeButton).click();
        }
        consumerApp.$(AccountScreen.accountTab).click();
        consumerApp.execute('mobile: scroll', {'direction': 'down'});
        consumerApp.$(AccountScreen.logoutButon).click();
        consumerApp.$(AccountScreen.confirmButton).click();
        consumerApp.$(LoginScreen.emailField).waitForExist(7000)
    }
```

Comment: i don't know selenium, but I guess there is an option to make this case async, so you could use `await` or alternatively some kind of callback implementation of your code?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to go through the official docs at webdriver.io.

There is an api which serves your purpose. Using that i would update your function as below.

```
logout() {

consumerApp.$(HomeScreen.closeButton).waitUntil(() => {
    this.isDisplayed();
}, {timeout: 5000, interval: 500});

if (consumerApp.$(HomeScreen.closeButton).isDisplayed()) {
    consumerApp.$(HomeScreen.closeButton).click();
}
consumerApp.$(AccountScreen.accountTab).click();
consumerApp.execute('mobile: scroll', {
  'direction': 'down'
});
consumerApp.$(AccountScreen.logoutButon).click();
consumerApp.$(AccountScreen.confirmButton).click();
consumerApp.$(LoginScreen.emailField).waitForExist(7000)
```

}

Reference:

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForDisplayed.html
https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForClickable.html

Comment: if the first step fails. will the test fail or it will continue?. I want it to continue if the homescreen.closebutton is not found

Comment: sorry the answer is not useful. Note that I am using if statement so that fails the test can continue

Comment: are you able to look into this?

Comment: I am sorry. I have been a little busy. let me do it now.

Comment: I have updated my answer. this way is a little efficient than yours because it will wait only until the button is displayed rather than waiting for full pause.